# Convolution of 2 signals

Tags: convolution

What would be the convolution of these 2 signals? :

$$x_1(t)=A\cos(2\pi ft), -\infty<t<\infty$$
$$x_2(t)=\cos(2\pi ft), -\infty<t<\infty$$

I know the formula of the convolution :
$$(x_1 * x_2)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x_2(\tau) \cdot x_1(t-\tau) \, d\tau$$
but I don't know how to use it for this problem

Answer (score 1):

$$ x_1(t)\circledast x_2(t) = x(t)$$

Use the property of Convolution

$$ x(t) = x_1(t)\circledast x_2(t)$$

$$ \frac{dx(t)}{dt} =  x_1(t)\circledast \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}$$

$$Or$$

$$ \frac{dx(t)}{dt} =  x_2(t)\circledast \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}$$

$$ \frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2} =  x_1(t)\circledast \frac{d^2x_2(t)}{dt^2}$$

$$ \frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2} =  - \omega^2 Acos(\omega t)\circledast  cos(\omega t) $$

$$x(t) = Acos(\omega t)\circledast  cos(\omega t) $$

$$ \frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2} =  -\omega^2x(t) $$

$$ \frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2} + \omega^2x(t) = 0$$

Now the whole problem has reduced into an 2nd order linear differential equation

$$m^2+ \omega^2= 0$$

$$m = +i\omega ; -i\omega$$

$$x(t) = C_1 e^{i\omega t} + C_2 e^{-i\omega t}$$

Now how to find the Constants

Use Laplace Transformation

$$X(s) = \frac{C_1s + i\omega C_1+ sC_2 - i\omega C_2}{s^2+\omega^2}$$

From question

$$X(s) = \frac{As^2}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}$$

$$(C_1+ C_2)s +i\omega(C_1-C_2)= \frac{As^2}{s^2+\omega^2}$$